# Cannot set value of select element inside component with Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I've been trying to set the value for a select element inside the `Dropdown` component, but the test keeps failing.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-stallman-stf98?file=/src/Dropdown.tsx) is a codesandbox of the component to test.

```
it('should execute onChange once and change value to "item2"', () => {
        const onChangeMock = jest.fn();
        const wrapper = mount(
            <Dropdown{ ...args } 
                onChange={ onChangeMock } 
                listItems={ ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'] } />
        );

    
        wrapper.find('select').simulate('change', { value: 'item2' });

        console.log(wrapper.debug());
        console.log(wrapper.find('select').props());
        
        expect(wrapper.find('select').props().value).toBe('item2');
        expect(onChangeMock.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
    });
```

Output after running `npm run test`:

> ```
>  expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality
>  Expected: "item2"
>  Received: undefined
>
>  51 |         console.log(wrapper.find('select').props());
>  52 |         
>  53 |         expect(wrapper.find('select').props().value).toBe('item2');
>     |                                                      ^
>  54 |         expect(onChangeMock.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
>  55 |     });
>  56 | });
> ```

```
console.log
    <Dropdown id="" name="" label="" placeholder="" errorMessage="" valid={false} required={false} listItems={{...}} onChange={[Function: mockConstructor] { _isMockFunction: true, getMockImplementation: [Function (anonymous)], mock: Object [Object: null prototype] { calls: [ [ SyntheticBaseEvent { _reactName: 'onChange', _targetInst: [Object], type: 'change', nativeEvent: [Object], target: [Object], currentTarget: null, eventPhase: undefined, bubbles: undefined, cancelable: undefined, timeStamp: 1637655017281, defaultPrevented: undefined, isTrusted: undefined, isDefaultPrevented: [Function: functionThatReturnsFalse], isPropagationStopped: [Function: functionThatReturnsFalse], value: 'item2', _dispatchListeners: null, _dispatchInstances: null } ] ], instances: [ undefined ], invocationCallOrder: [ 1 ], results: [ Object [Object: null prototype] { type: 'return', value: undefined } ] }, mockClear: [Function (anonymous)], mockReset: [Function (anonymous)], mockRestore: [Function (anonymous)], mockReturnValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)], mockResolvedValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)], mockRejectedValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)], mockReturnValue: [Function (anonymous)], mockResolvedValue: [Function (anonymous)], mockRejectedValue: [Function (anonymous)], mockImplementationOnce: [Function (anonymous)], mockImplementation: [Function (anonymous)], mockReturnThis: [Function (anonymous)], mockName: [Function (anonymous)], getMockName: [Function (anonymous)] }}>
      <div className="med-dropdown">
        <label htmlFor="" className="med-dropdown__label">
           (Optional)
        </label>
        <select id="" name="" className="med-dropdown__select false" defaultValue={0} onChange={[Function: mockConstructor] { _isMockFunction: true, getMockImplementation: [Function (anonymous)], mock: Object [Object: null prototype] { calls: [ [ SyntheticBaseEvent { _reactName: 'onChange', _targetInst: [Object], type: 'change', nativeEvent: [Object], target: [Object], currentTarget: null, eventPhase: undefined, bubbles: undefined, cancelable: undefined, timeStamp: 1637655017281, defaultPrevented: undefined, isTrusted: undefined, isDefaultPrevented: [Function: functionThatReturnsFalse], isPropagationStopped: [Function: functionThatReturnsFalse], value: 'item2', _dispatchListeners: null, _dispatchInstances: null } ] ], instances: [ undefined ], invocationCallOrder: [ 1 ], results: [ Object [Object: null prototype] { type: 'return', value: undefined } ] }, mockClear: [Function (anonymous)], mockReset: [Function (anonymous)], mockRestore: [Function (anonymous)], mockReturnValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)], mockResolvedValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)], mockRejectedValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)], mockReturnValue: [Function (anonymous)], mockResolvedValue: [Function (anonymous)], mockRejectedValue: [Function (anonymous)], mockImplementationOnce: [Function (anonymous)], mockImplementation: [Function (anonymous)], mockReturnThis: [Function (anonymous)], mockName: [Function (anonymous)], getMockName: [Function (anonymous)] }} onFocus={[Function: onFocus]} onBlur={[Function: onBlur]} disabled={[undefined]}>
          <option disabled={true} value={0} />
          <option value="item1">
            item1
          </option>
          <option value="item2">
            item2
          </option>
          <option value="item3">
            item3
          </option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </Dropdown>
```

Comment: Can you provide the code of the component? Make it as a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @slideshowp2 added

Comment: can you add test file in your codesandbox url?

Comment: @ShubhamVerma added

Comment: The `select` is neither a controlled component nor an uncontrolled component.  How did you get the option value in your component?

Comment: @slideshowp2 I've just set every option with its corresponding value, while creating the list of options dynamically. You can check that in the codesandbox.

Answer (score 0):

You are simulating onChange which means when unit test will try to call onchange, mocked function will execute (dropdown value wont be changed - that's real code not mocked code)

Which means the expect(ation) of expecting the component's value to change when you call "change" event (via simulate) is incorrect

So, `onChange={ onChangeMock }` causes mocked (jest.fn()) to be executed (rather than component's "real code")

What is correct expect(ation) is that when you simulate the "change" event for your component
(via code
`wrapper.find('select').simulate('change', { value: 'item2' });`
), then the onChange event should be triggered, which is correctly validated via the code
`expect(onChangeMock.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);`

On a slightly tangential note, don't test the "change" event - a user wont use code (change event) to select dropdown value so you should not test that. And you do not have to test the native  functionality either. You can use snapshot testing if you like to ensure that when you change `value` of the `<select>`, the new value is displayed. Related reading: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/testing-implementation-details